# Show an AlertDialog based on the MainActivity execution intervals

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

How to display an `AlertDialog` based on the number of execution of an activity(`MainActivity`).  For example if `MainActivity` is opened for 5 times then i need to display an `AlertDialog`.

Comment: you can do this by using a `shared Preference` variable ,to be incremented each time activity is opened and checking each time its value at the start of activity then showing `alertDialog`

Comment: @vipul_asri Post the code here, by adding following code it self will increment the count??     is this is correct way??         SharedPreferences prefs; 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

editor = prefs.edit(); 
        editor.putInt("count", count++); 
        editor.commit();)

Comment: yes your code is fine. Look at my answer you will find it easy to understand and implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saving data in Preference:**

```
private static void saveCounter(Context context, int value) {
 SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 
 editor.putInt("count", value); 
 editor.commit();
}
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
private static int getCounter(Context context) {
 SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 

 try {
        return prefs.getInt("count", 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

These methods will make your work easy and you just have to pass the incremented value to `saveCounter` for saving the value and then for getting the value use `getCounter`

Answer (score 1):

Dear archana,
              Please save the varible/flag in SharedPreferences. Check varialble value (whether 5)  then increment on every execution of activity until 5 and save to sharedprefrences and get it from there with every launch of activity.
In oncreate method of activity please update the variable with increment+1 and save it and check it in next launch

For more visit:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am not getting how to increment count every time if an Activity starts/execute.Can you please post the code here.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your counter to 0 and increment it in `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods of your activity. As soon as you increment these values, store these values in Shared Prefrences(as described in above answer). If you have trouble using Shared Preferences, try [TinyDB](https://github.com/pipipzz/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo), it is based on Shared Preferences and is much easier to handle.